# Bootstrap card overlay another card (images)

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

How do we achieve this using bootstrap?

I think it is card over card with image overlay.

[image]

Any one can help?

Comment: can you share your code or working demo?

Comment: Please show what you've attempted so far. ["Can someone help me?" Is not a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check below snippet

```css
.c {
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 16px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.c img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 3px;
  /* background-color: white; */
  box-shadow: 0 3px 20px 11px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
}

.c .top-sec {
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="card c">
        <div class="top-sec">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-sec">
          <p> Some data here</p>
          <p> Some data here</p>
          <p> Some data here</p>
          <p> Some data here</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this page and use the below html instead of the one given in example
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_cards2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    width: 40%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

img {
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
        width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    top: -50px;
}

.container {
    padding: 2px 16px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2></h2>

<div class="card">
  <img src="img_avatar2.png" alt="Avatar">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>Jane Doe</b></h4> 
    <p>Interior Designer</p> 
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because there is difference between your result and actuall question. You car using card, there is no overlap of cards.

Comment: It says “I think it is card over card with image overlay.” The keyword being “think” here!! the question didnt say that it has to be that way. The question was “How do we achieve this using bootstrap?” If someone downvoted my ans because of this reason better check the question again !

Comment: The good/bad thing about html and css is that there are hundreds of ways implementing the same thing. I just implemented according to what I thought was right.